# Which is correct: "Kiom da jaroj vi havas?" or "Kiom da jarojn vi havas?"

Tags: accusative

It seems like I only see *Kiom da jaroj vi havas?* but I don't understand why it would be correct.

Which is correct, between *Kiom da jaroj vi havas?* and  *Kiom da jarojn vi havas?*

Answer (score 14):

*Da* is a preposition. You don't use an -n after a preposition unless the preposition shows a location and there is motion toward the location, which doesn't apply here.

*Kiom* is actually an adverb and also doesn't ever take an accusative.

So *Kiom da jaroj vi havas?* is correct.

Answer (score 8):

I very much like how lernu.net presents it. I'll try something similar here.

To understand *kiom da*, we should begin with looking at *da*-constructions in general.

> *Li havas **amason** da pomoj.*
>
> He has *amason*, that is the object here. Think of *da pomoj* as a description of the object.

Here are some more examples:

> *Ni bezonas **kilogramon** da faruno.*
>
> *Vi trinkis **litron** da akvo.*
>
> *Mi vidis **plurajn botelojn** da suko en la fridujo.*

The words *kiom, tiom, iom, tro* and *multe* are not nouns and does not take the accusative-ending, but you can still think of the *da*-phrase as a description.

> *Ĉi tiu kuko enhavas tro da sukero, laŭ mi.*
>
> *Ili ricevis multe da laŭdoj pro sia bona laboro.*
>
> *Ŝi ŝatus iom da kafo.*

Along with numbers, *da* is not used, and the accusative steps in as usually.

> *Li havas dek pomojn.*

I believe this is why so many are confused by the very question you are bringing up. The answer almost never contains a *da* construction, and often the accusative-n, which clashes with the way the question is built.

> *Kiom da jaroj vi havas?*
>
> - *Mi havas **dudek-kvin** jaroj**n**.* (a number is standard)
> - *Mi havas tro multaj**n**!*
> - *Mi havas **tro da** jaroj.*
> - *Mi havas **dekojn da** jaroj.*

Answer (score 2):

The first one. After "da" you don't use the accusative. It's actually because the object is "kiom," the "of years" part tells you what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the tekstaro for the following:

```
 Kiom da \w+oj [mvnlŝ]i \w+[iaou]s

 Kiom da \w+ojn [mvnlŝ]i \w+[iaou]s
```

The first one you mentioned is correct because **da** is a preposition. Have a look at this page for more detials: http://esperanto.50webs.com/EsrGrammar-3_10.html

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT: This answer is incorrect as pointed out in the comments.

---

I just want to add some points to what others mentioned.

What I do to identify an accusative is to [*ask what*](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/accusative_case.htm) to the verb. If you can answer that without breaking the meaning, then that answer will be the accusative or direct object. **Put an -n at the end of it.** If you can't answer that then the sentence does not have an accusative.

Eg:

> I like you - (Like what? You!) - Mi ŝatas *vin*
>
> What are you singing? - (Singing what?) - *Kion* vi kantas?

In your sentence, you won't get an answer like this. So there's no direct object.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The answer to the question "kiom da jaroj vi havas" is indeed something like "mi havas dudek jarojn" -- I have 20 years. Have what? 20 years. The question, however, is why "kiom da" doesn't take an accusative, even when your rule of thumb would suggest that it does. This has been answered in the other answers to this question.

Comment: Oh! I'm a beginner and I was using tips like these to remember things. Thank you so much for correcting that. Your comment is really helpful.